# Is the given sentence grammatically correct? What difference does the insertion of comma where it's been inserted make?

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation

I almost had a heart attack, not finding the money where it was supposed to be.

Does the above sentence mean - I almost had a heart attack (out of shock) because I couldn't find the money where I had kept it? 
Is it grammatically correct?
What difference does how there is a comma where it is make?

Comment: Not finding .... is an absolute construction.  The comma makes no semantic difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this sentence is right to me and you understand it right. I think the comma helps clarify the logic because the "finding" part is somehow independent to the part before the comma. In other words you are free to delete the comma. By the way, I'm not an English native speaker.